# ARM7 Cross-Compiling: lacking symbols in elf file

Tags: c++, c, arm, cross-compiling

I have little problem with cross-compiling.
I use ARM7 bare-metal on LPC2378 IC and compiled binary from Eclipse internal builder on WinXP so far.

Now I need to change system, so i tried to compile it on new machine and this does not work: after compilation in elf file, a lot of symbols are missing (working have ~500kb, unworking ~10kb, also checked with objdump), but no errors.

For example, in elf i cannot find reference to main func.

I use arm-none-eabi toolchain in both cases. On the new machine I tried with the newest version of the toolchain (cross-compilation on Ubuntu 20.04 64b WindowsSubshellLinux) and the same as an old machine (4.9, cross-compilation on Ubuntu32b, virtual machine).

To compile commands was used:

Compile sources:

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=arm7tdmi-s -march=armv4t -marm -mlittle-endian -mfloat-abi=soft -Os -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -std=gnu++11 -fabi-version=0 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wextra -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Wfloat-equal -Wall -Wabi -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wnoexcept -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Wsign-promo -Weffc++ <my_local_flags> -I<paths_to_includes> -c -o <path_to_o_file> <path_to_cpp_source>

arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=arm7tdmi-s -march=armv4t -marm -mlittle-endian -mfloat-abi=soft -Os -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -std=gnu11  -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wextra -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Wfloat-equal -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wbad-function-cast     <my_local_flags> -I<paths_to_includes> -c -o <path_to_o_file> <path_to_c_source>
```

Linking:

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=arm7tdmi-s -march=armv4t -marm -mlittle-endian -mfloat-abi=soft -Os -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wextra -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Wfloat-equal -Wall -T<path_to_linker_script> -Xlinker --gc-sections -Wl,-Map,<path_to_map> -o <path_to_elf_file> <paths_to_o_files>
```

Path:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramFiles/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2020.424.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/home/user/env/gcc-arm-none-eabi/9-2020-q2-update/bin
```

Toolchain was downloaded as precompiled binaries from official site (https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/)

Anyone have similar problem?
Thanks for help

UPDATE:

I read both elf files using readelf from arm toolchain and in one is no entry point:

Working elf:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x3000
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          538908 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000202, has entry point, Version5 EABI, soft-float ABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         4
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         14
  Section header string table index: 11
```

Unworking elf:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x3000
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          82820 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000200, Version5 EABI, soft-float ABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         4
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         14
  Section header string table index: 13
```

Manipulating with g++ flags (-fdata-sections, -Xlinker --gc-sections, -T on end of command) didn't help.

Comment: Generally, elf binaries do not need symbols to work. They require entry points, which are visible when using `readelf -h` command (on linux, don't know what the corresponding utility on Windows is). _Edit_: Since you are running on WSL, you can use install and use readelf.

Comment: In your case, `-fdata-sections` along with `--gc-sections` will lead to stripped binaries. If you look at the manpage for gcc, under the section `-fdata-sections`, it is written: 'Together with a linker garbage collection (linker --gc-sections option) these options may lead to smaller statically-linked executables (after stripping).'

Comment: in general, linkers process the command line in the order it is written.  Therefore, suggest that the pointer to the linker script be last on that command line

Comment: I don't think entry point is relevant. Other than a Linux system, a MCU doesn't need an entry point or *main* functions. Instead, it expects a vector table at a specific address and takes the start address from the vector table. I'm surprised the .elf file is so small. The linker must merge the code of all .o files. Are you sure you have specified all .o files? What's their combined size?

Comment: Do you use identical linker scripts on both systems?